# python return wrong result when I multiple float with int

Tags: python-3.x

I have a multiple in python 3.7.3
when I run 0.58 * 100 it return 57.99999999999999

Then I found that Java have same result. But C can return right number. I don't know what happen with them. Sorry if it look like basic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its actually not the wrong answer, just an unexpected one.

If we think a bit about the problem, There are an *infinite* amount of numbers between 0 and 1. Then we can see that you cannot represent *all* numbers between 0 and 1 with a *finite* amount of bytes, as infinite numbers are more then a finite number of numbers. so some numbers just cant be represented (in fact, most numbers of the infinite series between 0 and 1 cannot be represented)

Following the floating point standard ([IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)), `0.58` is really `0.5799999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875` which is the closest number to 0.58 that can be represented with 64bit floating points.

check it with python

```
>>> Decimal(0.58)
Decimal('0.57999999999999996003197111349436454474925994873046875')
```

If you want 58.0 you can quantize it to two decimals with the Decimal class.

```
>>> Decimal(100 * 0.58).quantize(Decimal('.01'))
Decimal('58.00')
```